# Eventbrite feeds: how to have a specifc feed for a Event with multiple dates

Tags: xml, rss, feed, eventbrite, drupal-feeds

So I am pretty new to Eventbrite but I have been doing extensive research on how to use the XML feeds to pull out events. I have a particular event (Stand Up Trivia) that runs on multiple dates:

http://www.eventbrite.com/e/standup-trivia-tickets-13271825387

With the organizer list events XML feed, I was able to to view all events as a feed:

https://www.eventbrite.com/xml/organizer_list_events?app_key=MYAPPKEY&id=MY_ID

The issue I am having is singling out that event title from the organizer_list_events. I have tried the event_search parameter as well with no luck.

Does anyone know how to get a unique XML feed from Eventbrite of a specific title under my ID but has multiple dates associated to it which shows all those dates for that specific title?

The flip side to this also is I am trying to get this feed to work in Drupal to pull in, so it would be best to use the Eventbrite RSS (http://www.eventbrite.com/rss/organizer_list_events/MY_ID), does anyone know how to customize this URL to show events only for a specific title?

Answer (score 0):

This is my first answer on Stack Overflow, so take it with a grain of salt.

I've implemented, in PHP, a cron job that pulls all event data from EventBrite to my website, however using JSON rather than XML.  I've modified that to somewhat fit what you are looking for.

Assuming you are not running up agains API limits, you can pull the entire feed and then sort on the results.

```
function searchEventsByTitle ($searchTitle){
 $aEvents = array();
 $request="https://www.eventbrite.com/json/organizer_list_events?app_key=$API_KEY&id=$ORG_ID;
 $json = file_get_contents($request);
 $events = json_decode($json);
 foreach ($events->events as $oEvent){
  $event=$oEvent->event
  if($event->title == $searchTitle) {
    array_push($aEvents,$event);
  }
 }
 return $aEvents
}
```

This will return an array of events with the title in question.  Modify to include your API_KEY and ORGANIZER_ID.

Comment: Thank you Briggs for sharing this solution, do you have the full PHP code so I can see the full code in action.

Comment: @Alpdog14 you probably don't need this anymore, but if anyone else is looking, Automattic and Eventbrite wrote a WordPress plugin to interact with Eventbrite's API: https://wordpress.org/plugins/eventbrite-api/. That's a good place to see the full code in action.